# Inconsistent queried results in Rally

Tags: rally

I tried query tasks that were last updated today by

```
queries.push({
  type:"task",
  key:"tasks",
  fetch:"WorkProduct,Name,FormattedID,ToDo,Owner,LastUpdateDate,RevisionHistory,Revisions",
  query: "(LastUpdateDate > 2012-07-17)",
  order: "LastUpdateDate desc"
});
```

then use the custom grid app to make a similar query with

```
(LastUpdateDate > "2012-07-17")
```

I notice that results from the first approach is a subset of the second. i.e. There are certain tasks that are updated after 2012-07-17 (I checked in the revisions) and are missing from the result of the first approach.

Could some one explain me this?

Comment: This could be a function of your Workspace and Project scoping in your App - how are these set?

Comment: I use a same account for both, with standard workspace and project scope in the app

Comment: I also checked the tasks that are missing, their work products are in similar iteration and release with the others, nothing special

Comment: Could it be a timezone issue?

Comment: UPDATE: the issue is there NOT when I query tasks that were updated today, but from several days ago (like, 10 days). I can clearly see that alot of tasks that were updated during that time period are missing from the query result of the first approach

Comment: I think the answer to my problem is that queried result from the first approach is limited to a short amount recently changed tasks (2-3 days)

Comment: I am not following you here. If you think you have figured it out would you be willing to post an answer to your question below so that others that benefit from what you have learned?

Answer (score 0):

What I found before when messing with the API that the result sets have a 200 limit on them.

So any query that could return more than 200 needs to be paged.

Hope this helps !

Comment: true, I realize that they limit the amount of returned results to some extend, but that was never shown on any document, causing confusion

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue when running the reports through the UI that I brought up with Rally's support team where the page would issue an error when trying to use the range functionality and combinations of > and <. They were unsuccessful in providing a fix for this, and I think they still hold this as a defect within their management. However, I was able to get a workaround going by using both the >= and <= operators as separate filters in order to produce a range.

My point in all this is that you may want to experiment with different operators.